# GCC: Undefined reference (Makefile issue)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Trying to compile these files with gcc under Makefile rules. Running gcc / make on cygwin.

Here's the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99
OBJECTS = simulation.o element.o

simulation.exe : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o simulation.exe $(OBJECTS) 

simulation.o : file_priorite.o element.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c simulation.c

file_priorite.o: file_priorite.h element.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file_priorite.c

element.o : element.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c element.c 

clean:
    rm -f *.o simulation.exe
```

And getting these errors:

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 52ms)
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -c element.c 
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -c simulation.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -o simulation.exe simulation.o element.o 
simulation.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:11: undefined reference to `construire'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:11:(.text.startup+0x17): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `construire'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:20: undefined reference to `ajouter_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:20:(.text.startup+0x69): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ajouter_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:23: undefined reference to `consommer_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:23:(.text.startup+0x76): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `consommer_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:23: undefined reference to `consommer_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:23:(.text.startup+0x86): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `consommer_element'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:25: undefined reference to `obtenir_taille'
/cygdrive/d/Dropbox/UQAM AUTOMNE 2014/INF7330/lab10/lab10/simulation.c:25:(.text.startup+0x96): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `obtenir_taille'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'simulation.exe' failed
make: *** [simulation.exe] Error 1
```

The problematic functions are all implemented in `file_priorite.c`.

Any idea?

Comment: You're not linking against file_priorite.o (and it doesn't get created since you didn't put it in OBJECTS)

Comment: To expand on @remyabel's comment. Look at the places you list `element.o` in the file and the places you list `file_priorite.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your build log doesn't include `file_priorite` in any form - that means you're not building/linking against it.  Add `file_priorite.o` to your `OBJECTS` line.

Comment: I knew it was something really dumb. Human error, woops. Thanks, I'll accept your answer ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have

```
OBJECTS = simulation.o element.o file_priorite.o
```